# Шаблон для парсинга номера телефона в человеческий вид

Tags: javascript

как на javascript лакончино конвертировать в переменной номер вида "74991234567" в "+7 499 123-45-67"?

Comment: Не так уж и лаконично, но: `'74991234567'.replace(/(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '+$1 $2 $3-$4-$5')`

Comment: Спасибо! Подходящий уровень лаконичности: подменять нужно всего в паре мест.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант не лаконичный, зато чуть быстрее регулярки, и с более человекопонятной маской:

```js
console.log(formatTel('74991234567', '+0 000 000-00-00')); 

function formatTel(tel, mask, char = '0') {
  let rslt = [], 
      tIdx = 0; 
  for (const c of mask)
    rslt.push(c === char ? tel.charAt(tIdx++) : c); 
  return rslt.join(''); 
}
```

[<kbd>`▶ Тест на jsben.ch ‎`</kbd>](http://jsben.ch/oSRj4)

Comment: Несколько контринтуитивно, но вариант без массива (`let rslt = ''; ...; rslt += ...; return rslt;`) оказывается в 2 раза быстрее (по крайней мере в Chrome): https://jsperf.com/ruse-1049070

Comment: @Yaant, Так-то строки иммутабельны, поэтому на каждой итерации будет создаваться новая - если даже V8 это оптимизирует, имхо не стоит надеяться на него в ущерб логике вещей))

Comment: Чем Ваш вариант, вы по ссылке-то кликните. :)

Comment: Меня самого такая разница в скорости удивила, я бы тоже без проверки сказал бы, что с массивом должно быть быстрее.

Comment: @Yaant, Похоже что я ошибся, и надеяться на эту оптимизацию *стоит*. Все браузеры которые оказались под рукой, конкатенацию выполняют быстрее. Плюс, нашлось объяснение на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299010/why-is-string-concatenation-faster-than-array-join Спасибо, это реально очень неожиданное и полезное открытие.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо :)

Comment: @yar85  Интересно будет кто-нибудь пытаться позвонить по номеру, который выводится в консоли :-) +7 499 123-45-67

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, если увидят в консоли на реальном сайте - вряд ли. Интернет быстро учит осторожности)

Answer (score 0):

Немного корявенько, но без регулярных выражений

```
const indexed = [0, 3, 6, 8];
const text = "74991234567";
    .split("")
    .map((c, i) => indexed.includes(i) ? `${c} ` : c)
    .join("");
console.log(text);
```

Comment: А как же дефисы между `123-45-67`?